# Pyrebase4 storage No value for argument 'filename'

Tags: python, pyrebase

I have been struggling with installing pyrebase on my second PC, which has the same python version 3.8.2 as my main PC, my main PC has this pyrebase script working properly

```
from pyrebase import pyrebase
import os
import time

project_root = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
keys_path = os.path.join(project_root, 'keys')
hylKeyPath = os.path.join(keys_path, 'ServiceAccountKey.json')


firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app({
    "apiKey": "aksdjalksjdlkajsdlkjalkdja",
    "authDomain": "lkjsakdjlkjsad.firebaseapp.com",
    "databaseURL": "https://asdlkasjldkjaslkd.firebaseio.com",
    "storageBucket": "asdasdadjaslkjhd.appspot.com",
    "serviceAccount": asdKeyPath
})

storage = firebase.storage()


def sleepCountDown(t):
    while t > 0:
        print(f"sleeping for {t} seconds...")
        t -= 1
        time.sleep(1)


while True:
    print('fetching data')
    files = storage.child('/').list_files()

    for file in files:
        if 'records/' in file.name:
            # get the file url path
            # print(storage.child(file.name).get_url(None))

            # downloads file
            storage.child(file.name).download(os.path.basename(file.name))
            # deletes file? kinda deletes the entire folder
            storage.delete(file.name)
    sleepCountDown(10)
```

But somehow I am not able to install pyrebase on my second PC so I had to install pyrebase4.

But it seems this one has some bugs and keeps highlighting `storage.child(file.name).download(os.path.basename(file.name))` saying that storage: No value for argument 'filename' in method call.

then when I run, it says "Crypto has no method or something"

anyone knows what is going on?

Answer (score 1):

Just noticed the syntax was different on pyrebase4, it's `.download(path, filename)` the documentation was outdated.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
storage.child(file.name).download(os.path.basename(file.name))
```

Use:

```
storage.child("filename").download(filename="filename" , path="E:/ddf/")
```

Where `E:/ddf/` is path you want to save your file.